# How to enable Account History Tracking in Scratch Org?

Tags: metadata, salesforcedx

I have a project with existing metadata that requires Account History Tracking to be enabled. I can't figure out how to spin up a scratch org with this enabled (or to have it automatically turned on when I force:source:push the metadata into org).

The Account.object-meta.xml file does contain `<enableHistory>true</enableHistory>` but that alone isn't preventing errors like: `The entity: Account does not have history tracking enabled (348:13)`

I don't see any scratch org preferences that would seem to control history tracking for anything except contract (IsContractHistoryEnabled). I tried IsAccountHistoryEnabled, just in case, but it complains because that's not a valid flag.

Thanks,

Comment: There is an ongoing discussion about this on the Success Community: https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F93A000000HTp1&fId=0D53A00003BauKc

Comment: I was not able to reproduce. Are you using force:source:push ? Can you share the metadata of your object ? Can you try pushing only these attributes (Account.object-meta.xml with <enableHistory>true</enableHistory> and YourField.field-meta.xml with <fullName>YourField</fullName><trackHistory>true</trackHistory>) ? Can you share your plugin version ? Sorry for the poor formatting here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Salesforce says that they've logged an issue in their system but do not have a fixed timeline as to when it'd be fixed, in the Success Community discussion pointed out by Fabien here: https://success.salesforce.com/0D53A00003BauKc

The current workaround suggested by them plus common sense says:

a) Strip down Enable History Tags from Scratch org metadata and add them when deploying to sandboxes.

b) Enable History tracking manually before pushing the code to the scratch org.

Comment: This doesn't work when you have to create a version of the package though

Answer (score 7):

Salesforce is taking its sweet time to fix this problem, so I've created scripts to help me prepare for deployment by switching out tags from the fields involved.

This is `prep4scratch.sh`, to take out the unwanted tags:

```
#!/bin/bash
# prep4scratch.sh - Prepare for deployment to scratch org
find . -name \*.field-meta.xml -exec grep -s -l -e '<trackHistory>true</trackHistory>' {} \; | xargs sed -i '' -e 's|<trackHistory>true</trackHistory>|<trackHistory>false</trackHistory><!-- Should be true -->|'
```

This is `prep4prod.sh`, to restore the original tags:

```
#!/bin/bash
# prep4prod.sh - Prepare for deployment to production or sandbox org
find . -name \*.field-meta.xml -exec grep -s -l -e '<trackHistory>false</trackHistory><!-- Should be true -->' {} \; | xargs sed -i '' -e 's|<trackHistory>false</trackHistory><!-- Should be true -->|<trackHistory>true</trackHistory>|'
```

*Note: `sed -i ''` is a macos specific notation, use `sed -i` (without the single quotes) on Linux.*

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is this a script your store in your main/default director? Is this something you could convert to a method that could be run on all paths defined in your `sfdx-project.json`? I have a deployment script that I'm working on and it would make sense to run this on anything that will be picked up `force:source:push` or `force:mdapi:deploy`

Comment: I store these scripts in a separate directory that I named `tools`, outside of the `main` directory. To give you and idea, my directory structure looks as follows: `./src/main/*`, `./src/test/*`, `./tools/*`. I haven't thought of automating it to the point that it will automatically be hooked to the `force:source:push` or `force:mdapi:deploy` commands. That would be very cool indeed! Tbh I was hoping Salesforce would have fixed it by now...

Comment: Note that these sed arguments, `sed -i '' -e` only work on osx. To use this in linux, remove the empty single quotes, just `sed -i -e`

Comment: Thanks, @AndyRay! I've tested - the empty single quotes are definitely needed on macos. I'll update the answer to make note of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable Account History Tracking for new scratch orgs in your scratch org definition file using the `enableAccountHistoryTracking` flag under `accountSettings` which is under `settings`. For example, the following scratch org definition file enables history tracking for Accounts, Contacts, Leads, and Opportunities:

```
{
  "orgName": "Test Org",
  "edition": "Developer",
  "settings": {
    "accountSettings": {
      "enableAccountHistoryTracking": true,
      "enableContactHistoryTracking": true
    },
    "leadConfigSettings": {
      "doesTrackHistory": true
    },
    "opportunitySettings": {
      "enableOpportunityFieldHistoryTracking": true
    }
  }
}
```

Source: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_accountsettings.htm